# How can I perform unaryunion function in geos-C++

Tags: c++, geos

I am new to geos on C++. I am trying to perform UnaryUnion on two polygons.
What I did is here: (but failed)

```
geos::operation::geounion::UnaryUnionOp 
  un_polys(std::unique_ptr<geos::geom::Geometry> poly1,
           std::unique_ptr<geos::geom::Geometry> poly2);
geos::geom::Geometry* unionGeo = un_polys.getResultGeometry(
        geos::operation::geounion::UnaryUnionOp::  ???  ) ;
```

How can I use the `UnaryUnion` for polygons?

Comment: You didn't use that code.  What *did* you use? What error did you get?

Comment: Incidentally, as it stands, you have declared a function `un_polys`, and you are trying to access a member - except functions don't have members.

Comment: I am not sure the way I followed is correct. g++ says: "error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
     geos::geom::Geometry* unionGeo=un_polys.getResultGeometry(geos::operation::geounion::UnaryUnionOp ??? here ???) ; "